# Is it possible to set a variable that accepts multiple types in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm making a calculator and I'm stuck on the displayed number. Since calculation results and entries can be either an integer or a float, is there a way to set a single variable for the displayed number that can accept both of these types of numbers?

At the moment I have the numbers intended for display as NSNumbers, but I'm not sure how to get the variable to accept that type, and I'm not sure if it would be easier to get the variable to accept both floats and integers. Any advice would be very appreciated! Please pardon if this is a super obvious question.

```
var firstNum = 0     // first num in operation
var secondNum = 0   // second num in operation
var firstNumDisplayed = true

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag
        case 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20: // number buttons (11-19) and decimal (20)
            if sender.tag < 20 {
                if firstNumDisplayed {
                    firstNum = NumberFormatter().number(from: String(firstNum)+String(sender.tag-10))!
                }
                else { 
                    secondNum = NumberFormatter().number(from: String(secondNum)+String(sender.tag-10)) }
                }
            else {
                if firstNumDisplayed { 
                    firstNum = NumberFormatter().number(from: String(firstNum)+".")    
                }
                else { 
                    secondNum = NumberFormatter().number(from: String(secondNum)+".")
                }
            }
}
```

The error I'm getting with this approach is: "Cannot assign value of type 'NSNumber' to type 'Int'"

Comment: NumberFormatter returns  NSNumber not Int, so you need to convert the return value of NumberFormatter().number(from: String(firstNum)+String(sender.tag-10))! back to Int and use.

Comment: @wgr, Why don't you just use Float for everything?

Comment: Better to use the `Decimal` type https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal

Comment: Thank you! I'll try with Decimal!